# Installing IE-7 64-bit on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

Okay, so I have a fresh install of Windows XP 64-bit (using VirtualBox), and I want to install IE-7.  Seems simple enough.

**Step 1:**

I go to the [**official Microsoft download**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/default.aspx) page and download IE-7 for 64-bit (which seems to be equivalent to IE-7 for Windows Server 2003):

[image]

**Step 2:** I download the `exe` installation file.

**Step 3:** I run the installer and it installs IE-7,

[image]

...and then prompts me for a restart, so I restart.

**Step 4:** After restarting, I load up IE from the Start Menu:

and....

[image]

...***it's still IE-6.***

So, what exactly am I doing wrong here?  I'm not getting any error, or anything.  The installation seems to be successful, but after restart I still have IE-6.

So, what am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: Is the IE7 64-bit listed anywhere (else) in your Start Menu?

Comment: @techie007, no Start Menu only says `Internet Explorer (64-bit)`, which is IE-6

Comment: Which service pack are you on?

Comment: @Tanner, I'm using Service Pack 2

Answer (score 1):

Ok, judging by the screen shot you posted, it looks like you grabbed the wrong version.

In your shot it says: "*For:  Windows Server 2003 64-bit*", which is what you get when you pick "Windows Internet Explorer 7 for Windows Server 2003 IA64", which is for 64-bit [Itanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium) CPUs, which you most likely do not have. :)

Instead, on that download page click "Change systems" and try choosing "Windows Internet Explorer 7 for Windows 64 bit Client/Server", which will then display "*For:  Windows Server 2003 64-bit and more...*", which I would suspect is the version geared for "regular" 64-bit CPUs and OS's ("x64/amd64"):

[image]

More info from SU: [Difference between ia64 and x64](https://superuser.com/questions/276994/difference-between-ia64-and-x64)

Comment: I don't think *Windows Server 2003 64-bit* is the same as Windows Server 2003 IA64.  If you select *Windows 64bit Client/Server* and click `Next`, then it refers to your selection as *Windows Server 2003 64-bit*.  Regardless, the file I downloaded was **IE7-WindowsServer2003-x64-enu.exe**, which is not **IE7-WindowsServer2003-ia64-enu.exe**

Comment: the `and more` text doesn't appear on IE-6 for whatever bizarre reason, but regardless the actual file I am downloading is `IE7-WindowsServer2003-x64-enu.exe` and NOT `IE7-WindowsServer2003-ia64-enu.exe`

Comment: Bizarre for sure. :/  Hopefully someone else has some ideas.